# External PGS subtitle track burned with FFMpeg is out of sync

Tags: ffmpeg, sync, subtitles

I'm using MakeMKV to create a digital copy of my BluRay discs and have created a script to do some processing on the resulting MKV file:

- resample (and downscale if wanted) the video
- convert a single audio track to both AAC and AC3 (for each language I want) and discard the "input" audio track(s)
- copy all subtitles for specific languages
- copy chapter marks

I want to extend the script to burn in a single PGS subtitle track. However, when I add the proper overlay filter the resulting burned in subtitles are out of sync.

In general, the script uses `mkvextract` to extract the relevant video and audio tracks and uses `ffmpeg` to convert these to new tracks. After conversion all output tracks are merged using `mkvmerge`.

For the subtitle handling I use `mkvextract` to extract the proper subtitle track to a `.sup` file and pass this as an additional input to `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i ./title_t00/in/title_t00.mkv.h264 \
    -i ./title_t00/in/title_t00.mkv.en.sup \
    -codec:v libx264 \
    -filter_complex "[0:v][1:s]overlay[v1]; [v1]scale=w=-2:h=480:flags=gauss[v2]"\
    -map "[v2]" \
    -sws_flags gauss \
    -crf 10 \
    ./title_t00/out/title_t00.mkv.h264
```

The filter takes the video track from the first input and the subtitle track from the second input and overlay both. This results in a new video stream `v1` which is passed through the `scale` filter and the result is saved.

As said, the overlay works but the subtitles are out of sync. Is there a way I can properly sync them?

Or is there some magic `ffmpeg` invocation that can do it all in one pass?

Comment: How much is the desync and is it constant?

Comment: For the example video it looks like the subtitles appear about 7 seconds before they should. Also, it seems to be remain constant throughout the video. Using `mediainfo` the videotrack is 29:20 long, the subtitle track 28:15. So I guess I need to add some time shift in the mix. How can this be determined automatically?

Comment: Also note that the subtitles are in sync when playing the original file so the information must be available somewhere

Comment: Don't extract the subtitles. Feed and reference the mkv directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into stream mapping I found the following solution:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mkv \
    -filter_complex "[0:v][0:s]overlay[v1]; [v1]scale=w=-2:h=480:flags=gauss[v2]"
    -map "[v2]" \
    -map 0:1
    -map 0:1
    -map 0:2
    -codec:v:0 libx264 -crf 10
    -codec:a:0 libfdk_aac -ac:a:0 2
    -codec:a:1 ac3 -ac:a:1 6
    -codec:s copy \
    OUTPUT.mkv
```

The filter will overlay the first video track with the first subtitle track, scale down to a height of 480p and map the filtered video stream to be the first output stream. The next two `-map`s pass the audio stream twice to the output so I can create both an AAC and AC-3 stream. The last `-map` is for the subtitle stream and this is just copied to the output.

This needs to be fine-tuned so it will support multiple languages for the audio streams, filter any unwanted subtitle tracks and also filter the burned-in subtitle track.

See [How to Map Streams in FFMPEG](https://github.com/stoyanovgeorge/ffmpeg/wiki/How-to-Map-Streams-in-FFMPEG) for more information on stream mapping.